# Jmeter - skip populating parameter/value, when csv value is empty

Tags: jmeter

For the purpose of my test i need to test api calls, and data is send as parameters using CSV as loop using while controller.

Everything is configured and working fine, for looping all the values.

[image]
[image]

And my csv file looks like:

```
TC_name, currency, money, offset, limit, expectedCode
test_case1,USD,1,3,3,200
test_case2,EUR,1,3,3,200
test_case3,EUR,1,,3,200
```

But, i need to test optional fields, like 'money', from the above pictures, and instead of creation another sample like:

[image]

and, i want to achieve within the same loop.

So, is it possible somehow when there is empty field in the csv -> test_case3, both parameter and value to be completely skipped, but the looping logic to be respected?

Coz, if i send parameter with empty value, i got response like: **required 'Money' parameter empty**,

so in this way i will be able to cover optional parameters as well

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Add [JSR223 PreProcessor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_PreProcessor) as a child of the [HTTP Request](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) sampler which parameters you need to modify
2. Put the following code into "Script" area:

   ```
   def newData = new org.apache.jmeter.config.Arguments()

   0.upto(sampler.getArguments().size() - 1, { idx ->
       def arg = sampler.getArguments().getArgument(idx)
       if (!arg.getValue().equals('')) {
           newData.addArgument(arg)
       }
   })

   sampler.setArguments(newData)
   ```
3. That's it, the PreProcessor will remove all HTTP Request parameters which don't have values.

In the above snippet `sampler` stands for the [HTTPSamplerProxy](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/index.html?org/apache/jmeter/protocol/http/sampler/HTTPSamplerProxy.html) class instance, check the JavaDoc for full details on all available functions. You might also be interested in [Top 8 JMeter Java Classes You Should Be Using with Groovy](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/top-8-jmeter-java-classes-you-should-be-using-with-groovy) article.